# ggplot2 - why does changing axis scale affect summary statistics of variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a the following data:

```
x <- data.frame('myvar'=c(10,10,9,9,8,8, runif(100)), 'mygroup' = c(rep('a', 26), rep('b', 80)))
```

I want to describe the data using a box-and-whiskers plot in ggplot2. I have also included the mean using a stat_summary.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(x=myvar, y=mygroup)) + 
geom_boxplot() +
stat_summary(fun=mean, geom='point', shape=20, color='red', fill='red')
```

[image]

This is fine, but for some of my graphs, the outliers are so huge, that it's hard to make sense of the total distribution. In these cases, I have cut the x axis:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=myvar, y=mygroup)) + 
geom_boxplot() +
stat_summary(fun=mean, geom='point', shape=20, color='red', fill='red')  +
scale_x_continuous(limit=c(0,5))
```

[image]

Note, now that the means (and medians?) are calculated using only the subset of data that is visible on the graph. Is there a `ggplot` way to include the outlier observations in the calculation but drop them from the visualisation?

My desired output would be a graph with x limits at `c(0,5)` and a red dot at 2.48 for group `mygroup='a'`.

Comment: Try     `library(ggplot2);
    library(ggbreak);
    ggplot(x, aes(x=myvar, y=mygroup)) + 
      geom_boxplot() +
      stat_summary(fun=mean, geom='point', shape=20, color='red', fill='red') +
      scale_x_break(c(1.5, 7.5))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scale_x_continuous` will remove those points not lying within the limits. You want to use `coord_cartesian` to "zoom in" without removing your data:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=myvar, y=mygroup)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom='point', shape=20, color='red', fill='red')  +
  coord_cartesian(c(0,5))
```

[image]

Comment: Is this generally considered good or bad form?  Excluding data from the plot then including in the summary seems off to me, but I'm not confident about it.

Comment: Not generally bad form (unless you use if to misrepresent something, of course). For instance, if I plot simulated infectious disease outbreaks, most of their trajectories would be a few cases over a few months, though due to stochasticity some may be super large and long (ie, a quick example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InWNl.png))- so for practical purposes it would make more sense to explore the relevant data by "zooming in" but keeping the summary stats the same (example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1tf3.png)) - so kind of a "yes and no" answer here :)

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Also as good practice I usually indicate that there are values out of range - for another example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zYYn.png) where values lying on the x axis are below (but their actual values are irrelevant) - they are so extreme that accommodating them in the figure would make all the points indistinguishable.